# Can a B2B customer ever be anonymous in Hybris?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

Is there any scenario where the B2B customer can be anonymous as well in Hybris?

The method:

```
public CustomerModel getAnonymousUser() {
    return (CustomerModel)this.getSessionService().executeInLocalView(new SessionExecutionBody() {
        public Object execute() {
            DefaultUserService.this.searchRestrictionService.disableSearchRestrictions();
            return DefaultUserService.this.getUserForUID(UserConstants.ANONYMOUS_CUSTOMER_UID, CustomerModel.class);
        }
    });
}
```

in `DefaultUserService.java` suggests that the anonymous user will be of type `Customer`.

Is there any scenario where it can be of type `B2BCustomer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't.

If you check in Backoffice, under Customers node, you can find an `anonymous` instance, and its type is Customer (if you check in Administration tab).

B2BCustomer is a subtype of Customer, and they share the same unique attribute: uid. So, you can't have another B2BCustomer instance whose uid is also `anonymous`.

Answer (score 2):

No.  AnonymousUser is the non-authenticated user that just picks up generic site default settings.  B2BCustomer is about specific individuals linked to specific B2BUnit (account structure) records, there is no 'generic' B2B user concept.